# Hardware to connect PC to analog TV

Tags: graphics-cards, video, television

I want to use a TV that is on my bedroom with the computer, the TV has awesome quality, I am yet to see a "flat" TV that matches its picture quality without the price going in the 10.000 USD+ in my country.

But the TV has only normal analog TV inputs (YPbPr for example)

But new card manufacturers seemly are really against analog output, not only existing ones only output high resolutions (for example have a minimum resolution of 1024x768), some new ones seemly have no analog output at all (the recently launched Fury series, Skylake CPUs, and GeForce 10 line), something that introduces even worse problems (in my country analog monitors are extremely common, I for example own a laptop with HDMI and VGA out, I never used the HDMI out, while the VGA out is wearing out because of constant use).

So, I need some way to connect my computer to a TV, without expending lots of money (ie: those 400 USD HDMI to analog converters are not acceptable).

I am wondering if someone (not necessarily AMD and nVidia) make new video cards that support it (better if it is PCI-e 1x, to not waste a 16x slot).

Or if the Sapphire 380X can do it with some adapter help... (when ATI still was named ATI, they used to sell some "All in Wonder" cards that could output to TV when coupled with an official DVI-I to YPbPr adapter that had some resolution dip switches)

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure that you won't find any modern hardware with lots of analog outputs. What kind of inputs are available on the TV? VGA? If so, you just need a card with DVI output, which is quite common and a DVI-to-VGA Adpater, which should be very cheap, if not delivered with the card.
Also, I wouldn't recommend using some sort of adapter or something to connect your PC to such an input. Picture quality will suffer and you will also encounter some serious input lags, so I don't think that this a desireable solution.

Comment: I found out how to make a converter from DVI (all 380X cards have it), to YPbPr, it uses only amps and resistances, so the only delay is the extra time the electrons need to go around the circuit, something I think can be considered negligible...

The problem is that this converter only converters the colour signal, and don't change the resolution, thus the GPU must be capable of outputting the correct resolution and timing signal in first place.

Comment: Could you please clarify a few things: What's your maximum acceptable price (less than 400USD?)? What's your target resolution (800x600?)? What input cables would be acceptable (VGA, YPbPr, ...?)? What output can you generate (e.g. HDMI, DVI, ...?) Do you want extra treatment for audio (e.g. split off digital audio?, convert to analog audio?)?

Comment: I am from Brazil, it is hard to choose an acceptable price, some stuff maybe will cost some absurd amounts of money here, while others might be cheap, for example when I was looking into PC chassis, I found lots of people selling new "Define R4" cases for 80 USD in US and EU, meanwhile here in Brazil the cheapest I found was used, and it was 550 USD

Answer (score 1):

You need a DVI-Male to VGA adapter:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002IWP87S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002IWP87S)

plus a [VGA to Component converter](https://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011407&p_id=8668&seq=1&format=2) to connect the PC to the analog TV.

Comment: The Monoprice link is dead.